# Silent installation mode pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

is there any way to install pgAdmin 4 in Silent mode?
I've tried /VERYSILENT /NORESTART but it doesn't seem to work - the pop up asking whether to install it for all users on this machine or just for this single user still comes up.

Does anyone know how to suppress this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`/ALLUSERS` will work.
It's not documented in the command line `help /?` for this exe.
But it is an INNO switch and it works for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install in user context, add /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.